# Concatenation of formulae in R

Tags: r, concatenation

Function `constrain` of the R package [diversitree](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/diversitree/index.html) takes a list of formulae as input.

```
formulae <- list(lambda1 ~ lambda0, mu1 ~ mu0, q10 ~ q01)
constrain(lik, formulae=formulae)
```

I would like to pass these formulae via a decision tree and concatenate them as needed.

```
f1 <- "lambda1 ~ lambda0"
f2 <- "mu1 ~ mu0"
f3 <- "q10 ~ q01"
```

How do I arrive at the above-shown list `formulae`?

Unsuccessful attempt:

```
formulae <- as.formula(paste(f1,f2,f3, collapse=","))
```

**EDIT 1:**

I do not know the precise number of respective formulae *a prior*, but let them be determined via a decision tree. The precise number of individual formulae (i.e., `f1`, `f2`, `f3`, etc.) that goes into variable `formulae` should thus not be hard-coded.

Comment: `Map(as.formula,c(f1,f2,f3))`?

Comment: If you don't know the number of formulas, you should not store them as indiviual variables, but put them together in a list. I also don't understand why you store them as character strings, but you probably have your reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
formulae = list(as.formula(f1),as.formula(f2),as.formula(f3))
```

If you originally have all string formulae in a vector, say `f <- c(f1, f2, f3)`, you may use

```
lapply(f, as.formula)
```

Comment: Your `lapply` solution is independent of the precise number of input string formulae and thus what I needed. Thanks!